# React effect hook not firing when using React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component supposed to create different pages (one per child) and display only the selected page:

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface SwitchProps {
  pageId: number;
  children: React.ReactChild[];
}

export interface SwitchController {
  setPage: (pageIdx: number) => void;
}

export const SwitchContext = React.createContext<SwitchController>({
  setPage: (pageIdx) => {}
});

const Switch = (props: SwitchProps) => {
  const [pageIdx, setPageIdx] = React.useState(props.pageId);

  const controller: SwitchController = {
    setPage: (pageIdx) => {
      console.log("Changing page idx to", pageIdx);
      setPageIdx(pageIdx);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect called");
    setPageIdx(props.pageId);
  }, [props.pageId]);

  return (
    <SwitchContext.Provider value={controller}>
      <div>{props.children[pageIdx]}</div>
    </SwitchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

And a component using it:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Switch, { SwitchContext } from "./Switch";

const Page1 = (props: { value: string }) => {
  const switchContext = React.useContext(SwitchContext);

  const onClick = () => {
    switchContext.setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      This is page - {props.value} <button onClick={onClick}>Go to 0</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [pageId, setPageId] = React.useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("The first page");

  const onClick = () => {
    setPageId(0);
  };

  const onClick3 = () => {
    console.log("Attempting to change to 1");
    setPageId(1);
  };

  const onClick2 = () => {
    setValue("I have been changed");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <Switch pageId={pageId}>
          <div>
            <Page1 value={value} />{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick3}>Go to next page</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Page1 value="Hello there" />{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick}>back</button>{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick2}>Change it</button>
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note how I am creating a context provider inside component `Switch` so that by default all components enclosed by it will be able to get the controller to change page.

---

### The problem

The issue is the following:

1. Start browser => page 0 shows
2. Click on 'Go to next page' => page 1 shows
3. Click on 'Go to 0' => page 0 shows
4. Click on 'Go to next page' again => nothing happens

I can see that from the time button 'Go to 0' is clicked, the `useEffect` does not trigger anymore in `Switch` when I click on 'Go to next page'.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because you are updating the context state value from `Page1` component and `useEffect` is listening to props changes. `App` component's `pageId` prop value remains 1 as `App` component is not aware that `pageId` has been updated to 0 by `Page1`.

The solution is to handle the `Go to 0` click event in `App` component.

```
const Page1 = (props: { value: string; onGoToZeroClick: any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      This is page - {props.value}{" "}
      <button onClick={props.onGoToZeroClick}>Go to 0</button>
    </div>
  );
};  

// App.js
export default function App() {
  const [pageId, setPageId] = React.useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("The first page");

  const onClick = () => {
    setPageId(0);
  };

  const onClick3 = () => {
    console.log("Attempting to change to 1");
    setPageId(1);
  };

  const onClick2 = () => {
    setValue("I have been changed");
  };

  const handleZeroClick = () => {
    setPageId(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>
        <Switch pageId={pageId}>
          <div>
            <Page1 value={value} onGoToZeroClick={handleZeroClick} />{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick3}>Go to next page</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Page1 value="Hello there" onGoToZeroClick={handleZeroClick} />{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick}>back</button>{" "}
            <button onClick={onClick2}>Change it</button>
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You are duplicating same state i.e. `pageId` in two components(App and Switch). You should restructure the components to use the state variable from context.